# Is it possible to define access controls over queries in Hyperledger?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have a set of queries that I created using composer's query language, is it possible to define permissions related to which participants can execute what queries?

I.e:

Participant X can execute queries L,M N and P

Participant T can only execute queries L and M

Comment: I believe the answer is 'only if you actually build the queries inside transaction functions (as opposed to being defined in queries.qry, where they could be exposed via REST APIs)'. Then if called from transactions - they can be controlled by Transaction-based ACLs eg.  ```rule RestricttoTraders {
    description: "Only Allow Queries by Trader participants"
    participant(p): "org.acme.account.AccountTrader"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.acme.account.*"
    transaction:  "org.acme.account.QueryTxn"
  action: ALLOW
} ``` .

Comment: Of course the target `resource` may already be subjected to ACLs to restrict what those 'participants' are allowed to see (in terms of query results)

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony yeah I thought of that as a workaround however I think that in a large network that would cause significant overhead if queries start getting logged as transactions. Unless this is already the case in the core architecture, then it wouldn't matter

Comment: In Composer there is the concept of 'read-only' transactions (see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts#read-only-transaction-processor-functions-query-processor-functions ) - not sure if you calling this from a client app, but there is an example in that doc link (ie for current business network)

Comment: You should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51323998/8211613

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony your 'read only transactions' coomment appears to be the solution I was looking for