# How to setup asset access control now that composer has been EOL?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Now that hyperledger composer has been [EOL](https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/composer/message/125) how can i go about creating asset access restrictions?
For example i wish to create an asset where only the current owner, and the previous owner can see the status of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you read the Fabric docs on this subject - see --> https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#attribute-based-access-control as well as this answer -> [How does Hyperledger Fabric enforces ACL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51323003/how-does-hyperledger-fabric-enforces-acl)